# VBA 2 Questions concerning variable scope and lifetime

Tags: vba, module, scope

I've run accross two issues on what I'm trying to do with VBA concerning a variable's scope and lifetime.

1. I have different subs which use the same variables over and over and over. For example an integer that defines a column as a date column, cDate, or app as Application. Since I have a sizable declarations section I wanted to put this in a seperate module using Global but this did not work. Does it matter how I set the procedure scope here? How can I do this?
2. Similar to Q1, what about intializing variables? Specifically, instead of copying and pasting the same block which finds column headers (e.g. cDate), I put it into its own procedure. I'm running accross many problems trying to get this to work. I would hope this is possible, maybe not.

Tell me if you need to see code. Tell me what ou want to see and I throw it up here. (PS- I have gone through VBA Help, MSDN, Goole, etc and there is something I'm not understanding here)

Edit: adding edited code because the real thing is pretty long. All sections are in separate standard modules. I had read Global declarations only work at the workbook level and below and so I also tried declaring and setting `app`, `wb`, and `wrk` as `Public` in each module (not shown here):
Here's my declarations:

```
Option Explicit

Global app As Application
Global wb As Workbook
Global wrk As Worksheet

Global cInvoice As Byte

Global iEndCol As Integer
Global lEndRow As Long
Global x As Integer

Global sString1 As String

Global rng As Range

Private Sub Not_Really_a_sub()
    'No code. I read that any declaration needed to be in a module 
    ' with a procedure. I tried it with out the dummy sub also
End Sub
 'green text, read me and notes
```

And the sub that does the calling:

```
   Dim modulevariables As Integer

Sub Calling_Sub()

 'doing things

 lEndRow = 1 'blah blah blah
 iEndCol = 1 ' blah blah blah
 app.Run "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Header_Finder"

  'Code using cInvoice etc.

End Sub
```

And the Header finder:

```
Private Sub Header_Finder()
  With wb.ActiveSheet
    For x = 1 To iEndCol
        If InStr(UCase(.Cells(x, 1)), UCase("Invoice")) > 0 Then
            cInvoice = x
        ElseIf .Cells(1, x) = "next thing" Then
            cNextThing = x
        End If
    Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Thanks already.

Comment: How do you mean putting global variables in a different module didn't work? When you ran your code, it gave an error?

Can you include your global declarations and your column header finding routine for starters?

Comment: Enter should not default to submit comment. every time. See the edit in original please.

Comment: Just to be clear, you haven't specified it anywhere, but I've assumed you're calling your variable initialisation code before accessing the variables, right?

Comment: And that, sir or madam, was the magic question. No I did not and was not aware of this. Can a numeric data type be initialised to 0? I would think so but want to be sure before tomorrow.

Comment: I'll put another answer up pertaining to initialisation and declaration so I can include some code to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

As this doesn't pertain to my other (non) answer, but once again I need to include some code, I'll put it here.

In your "variables" module you're *declaring* variables:

```
dim wb as Workbook
```

Before you can use this variable you must *initialise* it, i.e. give it a value (any of these examples will work, each are for different scenarios):

```
set wb = ThisWorkbook
set wb = ActiveWorkbook
set wb = Application.Workbooks(1)
```

If you *don't* initialise this variable before accessing it, like in this example:

```
dim wb as Workbook
debug.print wb.name
```

You'll receive the error: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

Only object variables require initialisation. Other data types do not. Simply put, non-object data types are as follows. Default values (initialised at declaration) are in brackets:

- Integer [0]
- Long [0]
- String [""]
- Double [0]
- Single [0]
- Date [0, or December 30, 1899]
- Byte [0]
- Boolean [False]
- Currency [$0]

Everything else is an object and requires some sort of initialisation. An example follows:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb as Workbook
Dim app as Excel.Application
Dim wrk as Worksheet

Set app = Application
Set wb = app.workbooks(1)
Set wrk = wb.sheets(1)

'If any of the lines preceding this line are skipped, an error will occur.
debug.print wrk.name
```

Sorry if you already know this (really, I am, this was a lot to write!) just wanted to make sure we're on the same page after our comment discussion above.

Comment: Don't apologize and your effort os appreciated. I've been learning by trial and error and so I have a lot of knowledge gaps. There are some bits I knew and others I didn't. Plus there is a lot of lingo and definitions I don't full understand

Comment: Well, there were multiple issues from still having some declarations in the subs and then another mystery where others just didn't initialise. BUT, moving the modules into a new workbook cleared this up. Thank you very very much for your help om this.

Comment: No problem at all. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Q1.

You can declare the variables at three different levels. The procedure level (which sounds like what you have been doing and want to move away from), module level or project level.

To declare a variable at a module level simply declare it outside the first procedure e.g.

```
Dim app As Application

Sub mySub()
...
```

This variable will be available to all procedures within the module. To make the variable available to procedures in other modules you can use the public declaration e.g.

```
Public app As Application

Sub mySub()
....
```

Q2.

The simplest way to do this if have a procedure which initialises the variables which can be called from other procedures as required. For example the below code creates a public variable called PubStr, initialises it in  the first procedure which is called from the second.

```
Option Explicit
Public PubStr As String

Sub InitVar()
PubStr = "Hello World!"
End Sub

Sub RunMe()
Call InitVar
MsgBox PubStr
End Sub
```

Running "RunMe" will call the InitVar procedure which initialises the public variable PubStr.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but I needed to include some code. As a test, I put the following code in one module (Module1):

```
Public wb As Workbook
```

And this code in another module (Module2):

```
Sub test()

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Debug.Print wb.Name

End Sub
```

This worked fine for me. Can you try to do the same in a new workbook and let me know how it goes? Also, you could try more explicitly specifying which variables you're referencing, like so (still in Module2):

```
Sub test()

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Debug.Print Module1.wb.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: no dummy procedure in Module1

Comment: Noted, no dummies allowed and I will try this tomorrow with actual file on my work computer. I tried it on my laptop with `Global` and it's good to know I haven't gone crazy.

Comment: "Module1.wb.Name" is interesting. Recently moved to xl2010 and I've tried to be more explicit _everywhere_. Quite often on the xl server there are several instances running lots of macros, each with Public variables, quite often with the same names - unexpected automation errors have occurred I suspect due to scope being too wide. Therefore being as explicit as possible is a good thing.